# How to check if an item is in a list (column) and select another column item value based on that in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet with:

[image]

**How can I create the URL (as shown in F4) given the input in E4, from the table in (B3:C7)?**

---

**SOLUTION**:
Thanks to the accepted answer, I managed to get this working with:

```
=HYPERLINK(INDEX(B4:C7,MATCH(E4,B4:B7,0),2)&"pathTo/"&E4, E4)
```

where I also added a hyperlink to the created URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a INDEX/MATCH-Formula:

`=INDEX(tblData[Base],MATCH(D3,tblData[Name],0)) & "pathTo" & D3`

[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to use your table references `tblData[Base]` etc., but managed to get this working with direct cell range for specifying table extent. It would have been great to see how to use the table references instead, as it would be much more clear. Perhaps you can add a few words how to use the tablData references?

Comment: select a cell within the data, choose Insert > table from the ribbon, check "table has header" --> then you will see a new tab on the ribbon Table Design --> there you can change the name of the table (left side of tab) --> then you cna use the column names within the formula. There are lots of tutorials around - look for structured references, eg. https://exceljet.net/lessons/introduction-to-structured-references